# dojo 1.8 - Inserting long html contents into domContruct.place()

Tags: dojo

Hi I have a problem with dojo's domConstruct.toDom and domConstruct.place. 
Which ever I use both domConstruct functions or only domConstruct.place, I can't seem to
place the long html list tags. 
Please see my script below:

```
var row = domConstruct.toDom('<ul id="list">
<li class="odd">
    <div class="bold">
        <a class="odd">Odd</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="even">
    <div class="italic">
        <a class="even">Even</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="odd">
    <a class="odd">Odd</a>
</li>
<li class="even">
    <div class="bold">
        <a class="even">Even</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="odd">
    <div class="italic">
        <a class="odd">Odd</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="even">
    <a class="even">Even</a>
</li>
```

```
<ul id="list2">
<li class="odd">Odd</li></ul>');

domConstruct.place(row,"CPane_Chart");
```

Please advise, thanks in advance

Clement

Comment: from what i can see that isn't valid javascript, your string  for the list is not properly formed, desnt't the explorer show any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't Dojo, it's that you can't have multi-line strings in JavaScript unless you escape the new line with a `\` at the end. So you could do something like this:

```
var row = domConstruct.toDom('<ul id="list"> \
<li class="odd"> \
    <div class="bold"> \
        <a class="odd">Odd</a> \
....
<li class="odd">Odd</li></ul>');
```

Personally, though, I prefer putting HTML like this into an external HTML file and using dojo/text to load it:

```
require(["dojo/text!myListHtml.html"], function(myListHtml){
     var row = domConstruct.toDom(myListHtml);
});
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/text.html

Comment: Hi Jeremiah, If I were to use the first method, It seems that I can't join two UL tags(list1 and list2) using "\" together for the variable row.   After reading dojo/text.html and if I were to use either method before applying domConstruct.place(), then I need to know how I can apply query, ie  for "list1"  or ".class "in the variable row. I also search for help in dojo/query but nothing helps. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Hi Jeremiah, It seems that I can use query, without involving  the variable although I needed variable row build DOm. It works. But hjow about joining two UL tags with "\" ? Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "joining two UL tags with \". Maybe either post a new question or update your question with a the code that's giving you trouble.